# Updated data is not showing in Room database while making changes in item in recycler view

Tags: java, android

Unable to fetch updated data in recycler view and in room database. While verifying the data in Data base inspector, the updated data is not visible. While debugging the code. I can see that updated data, but unable to view the data in database inspector

ContactRespository:

```
package com.app.mycontacts.Data;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.room.Room;

import java.util.List;

public class ContactRepository {

    private static final String DB_NAME="contact_db";

    private static ContactDetailsDatabse conDatabse;
    Context context;

    public ContactRepository(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        conDatabse= Room.databaseBuilder(context,ContactDetailsDatabse.class,DB_NAME).build();
    }
    //insert task to insert the data

     public void InsertTask(final ContactDetails contactDetails){

            new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                conDatabse.contactDetailsDaoDao().insertTask(contactDetails);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
                super.onPostExecute(unused);
                Toast.makeText(context, contactDetails.getFirstName().concat(" ").concat(contactDetails.getLastName()) + " is updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }.execute();

     }

     public List<ContactDetails> getContactsDetails(){
        List<ContactDetails> contactDetailsList= conDatabse.contactDetailsDaoDao().getAllContacts();
        return  contactDetailsList;
     }
    public void UpdateTask(final ContactDetails contactDetails) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                conDatabse.contactDetailsDaoDao().updateTask(contactDetails);

                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    public void DeleteTask(final ContactDetails contactDetails) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                conDatabse.contactDetailsDaoDao().updateTask(contactDetails);

                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }
     }
```

......................

UpdatedActivity.java

```
package com.app.mycontacts.Activities;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.app.mycontacts.Data.ContactDetails;
import com.app.mycontacts.Data.ContactRepository;
import com.app.mycontacts.Data.MyAdapterClass;
import com.app.mycontacts.R;

public class UpdateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, emailId;
    Button updateButton;
    ImageView closeButton;

    String cfirstNAme="", clastName="", cphoneNumber="", cemailId="";

    String firstNameToUpdate="", lastNameToUpdate="", numberToUpdate="", emailToUpdate="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);

        firstName= findViewById(R.id.firstNameUp);
        lastName= findViewById(R.id.lastNameUp);
        phoneNumber= findViewById(R.id.numberUpAddContact);
        emailId= findViewById(R.id.email_up);
        updateButton= findViewById(R.id.update_button);
        closeButton= findViewById(R.id.close_img_up);

        // get values from custom adapter

        Bundle data= getIntent().getExtras();
        if(data!=null){

            cfirstNAme=data.getString("fname");
            clastName=data.getString("lname");
            cphoneNumber= data.getString("number");
        }
        ///set values to UI

        firstName.setText(cfirstNAme+"");
        phoneNumber.setText(cphoneNumber+"");
        lastName.setText(clastName+"");
        ///update values

        updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (firstName.getText().toString().isEmpty() || lastName.getText().toString().isEmpty()
                        || phoneNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(UpdateActivity.this, "Fill Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else
                {
                    firstNameToUpdate = firstName.getText().toString().trim();
                    lastNameToUpdate = lastName.getText().toString().trim();
                    numberToUpdate = phoneNumber.getText().toString().trim();

                    ContactRepository contactRepository = new ContactRepository(getApplicationContext());
                    ContactDetails condetails = new ContactDetails(firstNameToUpdate,lastNameToUpdate,numberToUpdate,emailToUpdate);
                    contactRepository.UpdateTask(condetails);
                   // Toast.makeText(UpdateActivity.this, "Values Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });

        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in = new Intent(UpdateActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Tried debugging the code. And verified details in database inspector..

Comment: Don't use AsyncTask
Use viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

try to add not add adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

```
public void UpdateTask(final ContactDetails contactDetails) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                conDatabse.contactDetailsDaoDao().updateTask(contactDetails);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

Comment: its not working, i cant see updated details in Room db